# QGIS export to shapefile inflates real field size and value

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, export

At 3.8.3, when I **Export > Save As** a Geopackage point layer to a shapefile, fields with type = double are output with *15(!!!)* significant digits.  Here are the before and after field widths:

**Input:**
Type:    **double**
Length:   **10**
Precision:   **2**

**Output:**
Type:    **double**
Length:   **23**
Precision:  **15**

Furthermore, the output values are modified by a slight amount.  Here are some examples:

**Input**    **Output**
150.62   150.620000000000005
150.51   150.509999999999991
221.86   221.860000000000014

Unfortunately, based on the comment by @user30184, the QGIS shapefile output appears to be the default action.

Now I'm curious about the passage that @user30184 quoted, particularly the phrase "...Real (floating point) fields *without an explicit width*..."  This implies that my fields did not have explicit widths.

How do I make my real field widths *explicit*, either by modifying the source layer, or in the GDAL output process, or some other method?

Comment: Precision value seems to be close to GDAL default value https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html `Real (floating point) fields without an explicit width are treated as width 24 with 15 decimal places of precision.`.

Comment: You can use the Vector - Table - Refactor Fields tool to change field attributes like precision.  When adding a new field using the Field Calculator you tell it the field type, length and precision.